# Why is there a warning sign in paypal app profile - accept payments?

Tags: paypal, profile

[image: paypal app profil overview]

Hi there!

I recently created a paypal app in paypal developer, I entered informations on the app but still a warning is shown in the 'accept payments' area (see picture). Whats the error? ...there's no description at all!

Comment: I have the same problem and can't find any solutions. The issue is also raised here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580046/paypal-development-at-least-one-capability-must-be-turned-on and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588420/paypal-rest-api-app-status-need-more-info the 1st says profile details are missing & The 2nd link says we shoudl have recieved an email for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue currently where users aren't able to submit new apps on Developer.PayPal.com. There are a couple potential workarounds that you may want to check.

Ensure that your Developer.PayPal.com account has a first and last name associated with it and that you have a "facilitator" account saved in the "Sandbox accounts" section. If you don't have a "facilitator" account you can add one by just creating a new account with the e-mail address formatted like this - xy-facilitator@domain.com

I'll update this thread again when a fix is released or if more information is provided.

Edit: The issue where valid accounts were unable to submit an application should be fixed now. Make sure that the account you're requesting an app for is on this list and you should be good to go: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

Comment: I read somewhere that the REST API is only available to US customers. Could this be the problem?

Comment: REST is only available to US merchants but the issue I mentioned extends to US accounts not being able to submit an application. I'm not sure if the original poster is using a non-US account or not.

Comment: The countries supported for REST has updated this morning:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

Comment: From what I can see only us, uk, canada have access to the REST API. I'm in Ireland and was wondering if I'm covered because in my sandbox REST API calls are being processed successfully

Answer (score 0):

I recently done this on developer paypal portal.i had also this mark on my app but after filling the information and we need to include mass payment in our app so we just contacted paypal to enable this feature as this is disabled by default and developer needs to contact paypal to enable this.So now i have approved status on my app and no alert mark for any info.