# Paypal development "At least one capability must be turned ON"

Tags: paypal

I have created an app on developer.paypal.com

But my app status shows:

**Status: Need more info**

When i try to click to accepts payment, the site shows the message:

**At least one capability must be turned ON.**

---

Update:
Hardly discovered that the problem is in support to other countries. The rest api currently only works for the United States

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for your classic API app or access to REST credentials?

There is a messaging system through the classic API app site that you can use to respond to inquiries from the App Review team.

When you set up your account to submit apps did you add a first and last name? There is an issue with users without that information included being unable to submit an app.

Comment: Hardly discovered that the problem is in support to other countries. The rest api currently only works for the United States