# Paypal REST API app status Need more info

Tags: paypal

I have a verified Paypal account and I created a REST API app with the Mobile SDK integration type.

My app status still says "Need more info", and I'm not sure what to do next since my Sandbox account is not processing any payment.

Is there a way to have a more complete app status.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. What is the problem you're having with the with Sandbox? The REST and Mobile SDK's are completely separate from each other. When your app went into a "Need more info" status you should have received an e-mail you need to reply to.